# Logging memory allocation errors

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Let's say I'm trying to write a checked version of `malloc()` in C99 - nothing fancy, a simple wrapper, which if `malloc()` returns `NULL` will print an error message to `stderr` and quit. Something like

```
   void* checked_malloc(size_t size) {
        void* ptr = malloc(size);
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %zd bytes\n", size);
            exit(1);
        }
        return ptr;
   }
```

One of the problems with this is fprintf - which might attempt to allocate memory on it's own and since we are out of memory already will ungracefully fail.

Is there any way to reliably log an error message after failed memory allocation? Or is there a better approach to write checked `malloc()`? A compiler agnostic solution is hugely preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I think you are being too paranoid. Your current solution looks fine. There is no reason `fprintf()` should fail with `ENOMEM`. It's just going to turn around and issue `write()` calls to the file descriptor for `stderr` (2).  It has no reason to allocate any memory.

Of course, you could always try logging with direct `write()`s, like this:

```
static const char oom[] = "Out of memory!\n";
write(2, oom, sizeof(oom));
```

But again, that's probably overkill.

Also, you shouldn't worry about what every library call does regarding memory allocation. Using a checked `malloc()` is no substitute for good error checking elsewhere in your code.